# Homogenous diff equations of the form P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

thank you for taking the time to help me out. I am reviewing a past test while looking in my book to try to figure out how to do this. I understand the way to solve these types of problems, I only get stuck at determining whether they are homogenous or not. For example:

$(x^2 + y^2)dx + (xy) dy=0$ How do I know it is homogenous? All the book says is that it is homogenous of degree 2. I understand that once I am able to identify that, then I set $y=xv$ and the rest I understand, but how do I distinguish problems like this?

Another example from my last test, $(xy^2 - 2x^3)dy=(yx^2 + y^3)dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research session (aka studying for finals), I finally found a source that put it this way:

A function G(x,y) is homogenous of degree n if:
$G(tx,ty) = t^nG(x,y)$

Hence, if by replacing x and y with $\lambda x$ and $ \lambda y$ You yield the same function being multiplied by some power of lambda ($\lambda^n$) then you know the equation is homogenous with degree n.

Comment: An ODE is homogeneous if there is such function $F$ on the variables $ y ,y' ,y", ...y^{(n)}$ of the form $ F(y,y',y",...y^{(n)}) = 0$. This is for linear by the way, but extends to non-linear. This is by definition.

Comment: @dylan7 I think that these are two different "homogeneities": the OP's variant is about behaviour of functions with respect to dilations (and consequences of such a function being a RHS of ODE), and your's is about presence/absence of terms in RHS of equation. Wikipedia suggests even another one case for this term.

Comment: Ah, yes, I realize that now by looking at the OP's answer again.